# Why am I getting an Infinite loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return the factorial of the provided integer. When doing it like this, e.g:

```
factorialize(num) {
    for (var i = 1;i <= num; i++){
        num*=i;
    }
        return num;
    }
factorialize(5);
```

I'm getting an infinite loop. While I understand that this shouldn't give me the correct answer because my understanding of it would go something like this:

```
n! = 5 * 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 600
```

when really it should go:

```
n! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120
```

But still, I don't understand why I am getting an infinite loop here?

Comment: make another variable to hold the result. Rather than changing the value of the parameter.

Comment: @Lixus: Please answer in **the answer section** (clue's in the name)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets say that the value of `num` variable is `2`.

- First cycle:

  ```
  for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) { //true
     num *= i; //2 = 2 * 1 => 2
  }
  ```
- Second cycle:

  ```
  for (var i = 2; i <= 2; i++) { //true
     num *= i; //2 = 2 * 2 => 4
  }
  ```
- Third cycle:

  ```
  for (var i = 3; i <= 4; i++) { //true
     num *= i; //4 = 4 * 3 => 12
  }
  ```
- Fourth cycle:

  ```
  for (var i = 4; i <= 12; i++) { //true
     num *= i; //12 = 12 * 4 => 48
  }
  ```

The `num` value **increases exponentially**, while the `i` value **increases linearly**.

`i <= num` condition will be **always fulfilled**, that's why you are getting an infinite loop.

[image]

Snippet including the chart:

```js
var num = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  y: [2, 4, 12, 48, 240],
  type: 'scatter',
  name: 'num'
};
var i = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  y: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  type: 'scatter',
  name: 'i'
};
var data = [num, i];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;">
```

Comment: `num` increases exponentially, not logarithmically.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is chasing a moving target.

It will end when `i` reaches `num`, but you keep making `num` bigger; actually `i` will *never* reach `num`.

As you pointed out, your algorithm is wrong anyway.

```
function factorialize(num) {
   var result = 1;
   for (var i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
      result *= i;
   }
   return result;
}

console.log(factorialize(0));  // 1
console.log(factorialize(1));  // 1
console.log(factorialize(2));  // 2
console.log(factorialize(3));  // 6
console.log(factorialize(4));  // 24
console.log(factorialize(5));  // 120
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable that you use on the for loop it's the same variable that you use to store the multiplication.

This should work:

```
factorialize(num) {
    var len = num;
    for (var i = 1;i <= len; i++){
        num*=i;
    }
        return num;
    }
factorialize(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are dynamically updating the value of `num`. So, after each iteration, the number gets bigger and bigger, and that's why the value of `i` will never be more than the value of `num` (for values of `num` larger than 1).

Comment: It will if `num` is `<= 0` at the start of the function.

Comment: @BoundaryImpositio Yes you are right. But for value larger than 1, this will always be an infinite loop.

Comment: You said "never" :)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Just made an edit. Thanks for noticing this! :)

Comment: No problem Omar!

Answer (score 0):

Because you change the value of 'num' in every iteration. You should use a third variable to count the product.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an infinite loop because you are always updating num. You are doing `num = num * i`. So it can never reach the end of the loop. `i` will never be greater then `num`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your example:

Before run 1:
num = 5;
After run 1:
num = 5;
After run 2:
num = 10;
After run 3:
num = 30;

As per your condition, loop would stop only when num is more than i, which would never be the case, as you're modifying it's value on every iteration by a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

here `i` will never catch `num`

```
i = 1 num = 5  1 <= 5  //(num = 5*1)
i = 2 num = 5  2 <= 10 //(num = 5*2) 
i = 3 num = 10 3 <= 30 //(num = 10*3)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The end condition for `i<=num` is always `true` hence the infinite loop because the argument `num` keeps increasing with each iteration.
A better approach is

```js
function factorialize(num) {
  var res = 1;
  if(num ===0 || num === 1){
    return 1;
 }
   for (var i = 2;i <= num; i++){
      res*=i;
    }
      return res;
    }
factorialize(5);
```